# In OData standard, how to deal with $filter with multiple logical operator without parenthesis?

Tags: odata, rest

for instance, I tried the official example with queries:

https://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService/(S(q1skedyvlv22yjp5fcce2gg2))/People?$filter=UserName%20eq%20%27russellwhyte%27%20or%20UserName%20eq%20%27scottketchum%27%20and%20UserName%20eq%20%27ronaldmundy%27

and

https://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService/(S(q1skedyvlv22yjp5fcce2gg2))/People?$filter=UserName%20eq%20%27russellwhyte%27%20and%20UserName%20eq%20%27scottketchum%27%20or%20UserName%20eq%20%27ronaldmundy%27

It turns out that it is not from left to right, the AND operator was dealt in prior to OR operator.
I wonder if that is the rule.

I searched the document:
http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc453752358

it refers to odata-abnf.

But in abnf I only find

> "andExpr = RWS "and" RWS boolCommonExpr"

, which I fail to understand...

Answer (score 0):

AND in logic has higher precedence than OR, the same way that multiplication has higher precedence in math than addition. Expressions aren't evaluated left-to-right, either in math or logic. They're evaluated according to specific precedence rules.

Most (if not all) programming languages follow the logical precedence rules.